# How to search a Map and update value by using filter in Scala

Tags: scala

I have map `colValues: Map[Int, String]`, and data would be:

```
(15043 -> "226", 15044 -> "NA", 15045 -> "36", 15046 -> "0", 15047 -> "47", 15048 -> "NA")
```

I want to change all value with "NA" to "0" for `colValues`, we don't need other variable. In other words, after processing `colValues` would be :

```
(15043 -> "226", 15044 -> "0", 15045 -> "36", 15046 -> "0", 15047 -> "47", 15048 -> "0")
```

Comment: That's a pretty simple `.map()` operation. What have you tried? What didn't work?

Comment: You don't need `filter` for this. This is an example of an [XY Question](http://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 2):

You only need a `map`

```
colValues.map { case (a, b) => if (b == "NA") a -> "0" else a -> b }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `mapValues`:

```
colValues.view.mapValues(v => if (v == "NA") "0" else v).toMap
```

More likely, you want to convert to a `Map[String, Int]` though. One way to do that is

```
colValues.view.mapValues(_.toIntOption.getOrElse(0)).toMap
```